# how to echo once in a while loop in php

Tags: php

How could I echo only once in while loop condition? The number of echo I am getting is also the number of loop. Thank you very much for your help.

This is the code the part I am echo is in `if($countrow === 7){
}..`

```
<?php  
 if(!empty($_FILES["employee_file"]["name"]))  
 {  
      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");  
      $output = '';  
      $allowed_ext = array("csv");  
      $tmp = explode(".", $_FILES["employee_file"]["name"]);
      $extension = end($tmp); 
      if(in_array($extension, $allowed_ext))  
      {  
           $file_data = fopen($_FILES["employee_file"]["tmp_name"], 'r');  
           fgetcsv($file_data);        
           while($row = fgetcsv($file_data))  
           {
               $countrow = count($row);
               if($countrow === 7){
                $image = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[0]);             
                $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[1]);
                $rfid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[2]);  
                $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[3]);  
                $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[4]);  
                $Role = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[5]);  
                $Details = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $row[6]);                
                $query = "  
                INSERT INTO table 
                     (Column names)  
                     VALUES (values)  
                ";              
                mysqli_query($connect, $query);
               //echo should be here but the value is looping.
               }
               else
               {
                   echo 'There was something wrong in csv column';
                   break;
               }               
           }
      }        
      else  
      {  
           echo 'Please select a csv file';  
      }  
 }  
 else  
 {  
      echo 'Please select a csv';  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: Assuming the CSV file you are reading from here has the same number of columns in each row, `$countrow = count($row);` will always get you the same value - so not sure what you expect to happen here?

Comment: Do you want to do something here only when the 7th row of the CSV data was read? Then keep a counter variable that you increment on each loop iteration, and check _that_.

Comment: @misorude can u give example

Comment: "how could I echo only once in while loop" -> what do you want to echo? And when do you want to echo it?

Comment: Welcome. What is `fgetcsv($file_data);` supposed to do? Also there's an example on [the PHP manual for fgetcsv](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are counting columns in the row by using `$countrow = count($row);`.

I assume you want to get the 7th row. So just count as you loop.

```
$rowCount = 0;
while($row = fgetcsv($file_data))  
{
    $rowCount ++; 
    // your code
    if($rowCount === 7){
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u for answering @delboy1978uk but i am counting the column not the row.

Comment: i just name it $row

Comment: its for validation if(thenumber of row is 7)